# How to get the variables in php page sent from previous page via ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am making an ajax call from one php page to second.in which i m sending three variables.
But i m not able to get it in next php page where i m sending them ...
please check.
Index.php

```
function loadMoreData(offset){
var part1= "<?php echo ($part1);?>"; 

var part2="<?php echo ($part2);?>";

    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        async:false,
        url: 'getMoreData.php',
        data:{offset:offset,part1:part1,part2:part2},
        success: function(data){

            $(data).appendTo("#product");
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("ajax error occured…"+data);
        }
    }).done(function(){
        $(window).bind("scroll",function(){
        scrollMore();   
    });
    });
}


});
```

getMoredata.php

```
 <?php
    include('connection.php');

    $offset = (isset($_REQUEST['offset']) && $_REQUEST['offset']!='') ? $_REQUEST['offset'] : '';
    $limit = 10;
    $var1 = (isset($_REQUEST['part1']) && $_REQUEST['part1']!='') ? $_REQUEST['part1'] : '';

    $var2 = (isset($_REQUEST['part2']) && $_REQUEST['part2']!='') ? $_REQUEST['part2'] : '';

    $qry1 = mysql_query('select * from xml WHERE  PNAME LIKE  \'%$var2\' AND CATEGORY like \'%$var1\' limit ".$offset.", ".$limit."');
    print $qry1;
    ?>
```

I m able to send the three variables from index.php page but i m not able to get them in getMoreData.php,due to which i m not able to run the sql command...

Please verify guys....

Comment: when you use `$_REQUEST` its checking for both `$_GET` and `$_POST` , your request is always become `true` , so you need to define `$_GET` instead of `$_REQUEST`, so if `$_GET` is false use `$_POST`

Comment: Does it work when you call your php script directly with the paramteters like this:

`getMoreData.php?offset=something&part1=something_1&part2=something_2`

Comment: let me try this one @EugenTimm

Comment: I tried,directly its going when i m applying part1 and part2 on anchor tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$_GET` instead of `$_REQUEST`.

Also you are not sending the rows properly, use-

```
print_r(mysql_fetch_array($qry1));
```

Then try to check the response in browser's console with - `console.log(data)` and then manipulate it accordingly.

Comment: I tried with this sir.but i m not able to execute the query still..and how to check that variables have passed to getMoreData.php.I m doing echo those variables.nothing is getting printed.And please correct my query also...if any commas at wrong place sir..

Comment: Before sending to php, plscheck if `part1` and `part2` are correct

Comment: ya that i have checked,by printing in alert box.values are coming correct..Its going in the url also,checked in developer tools.but not doing anything on page..

Comment: In php file, just write - `echo $_GET['part1']` and see if you get this in response of ajax, `console.log(data)`. Try to debug like this, you'll get what the problem is

Comment: where should i put console.log(data)

Comment: lol.. after `success: function(data){` ofcourse! Is it the first time you are coding js?

Comment: its first time i m using ajax

Comment: One small problem sir.I am having total of 18 records to be displayed.10 records i m displaying in index.php and then on scroll i m getting next 8 records.The problem is on every scroll these 8 records are getting repeated.not stopping.can u please help me out on this..

Answer (score 0):

Try with this for all variables

```
$offset = isset($_GET['offset']) ? $_GET['offset'] : $_POST['offset'];
```